# this.props.login is not a function react-apollo + compose + graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

```
import { graphql, compose } from 'react-apollo'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

const AUTHENTICATE_USER_MUTATION = gql`
      query authenticateUserMutation($email: String!, $password: String!) { 
        login(email: $email, password: $password) {
          token
        }
      }
    `

    const LOGGED_IN_USER_QUERY = gql`....`
    export default compose(
      graphql(AUTHENTICATE_USER_MUTATION, {
        name: 'authenticateUserMutation',
        options: (props) => ({ 
           variables: { email: props.email, 
                         password: props.password } 
        })
      }),
      graphql(LOGGED_IN_USER_QUERY, { 
        name: 'loggedInUserQuery',
        options: { fetchPolicy: 'network-only' }
      })
    )(withRouter(Login))
```

After entering email and password on click of login function

```
OnclickLogin  = async () => {
  const { email, password } = this.state
  await this.props.authenticateUserMutation({variables: {email, password}})

}
```

It gives error **this.props.authenticateUserMutation** is not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, basically you are firing a query, but call it a mutation.

You have to exchange mutation for query, so that it looks like this:

```
const AUTHENTICATE_USER_MUTATION = gql`
      mutation authenticateUserMutation($email: String!, $password: String!) { 
        login(email: $email, password: $password) {
          token
        }
      }
    `
```

and on the bottom you do not need the options. You would need them if you would want to fire a query.

```
export default compose(
      graphql(AUTHENTICATE_USER_MUTATION, {
        name: 'authenticateUserMutation'
      }),
```